# GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect - Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, http, cpanel, guzzle

I'm trying to post a Third party Api with raw body with my controller , It works fine when I test it from localhost , but when I publish my project on the Server (Cpanel) , I get this Error :

GuzzleHttp\Exception\ConnectException: cURL error 7: Failed to connect.

Here is an example of my code inside the controller :

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Http;

    public function testApi(){
      $array = [
        'FullName' => 'Full Name',
        'PhoneNumber' => '9999999999',
        'Date' => '2022-06-26 17:20',
        'Note' => '',
      ];
      try {
        $response = Http::withBody(json_encode($array) , 'application/json')
          ->post('https://example');
        return $response->status();
      } catch (Exception $exception){
        return $exception;
      }
    }
```

and I also tried using GuzzleHttp and the same thing it works on localhost , and not working when I publish the project on the server.

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

    public function testApi(){
      $array = [
        'FullName' => 'Full Name',
        'PhoneNumber' => '9999999999',
        'Date' => '2022-06-26 17:20',
        'Note' => '',
      ];
      try {
          $client = new Client();
          $response = $client->request('POST', 'https://example', [
             'body' => json_encode($array),
             'headers' => [
                 'Content-Type' => 'application/json',
             ]
         ]);
        return $response->getStatusCode();
      } catch (Exception $exception){
        return $exception;
      }
    }
```

Comment: It's probably not an issue with your code, cURL is probably not enabled on the server.

Comment: Also, there can be a firewall that blocks your requests

Comment: If your site is using HTTPS / SSL, but it is not configured properly, then this could also lead your web server to block insecure cURL requests. To fix this, you can ask your hosting provider to re-install SSL certificate for your website.

Answer (score -1):

before disable firewall and test again.

there can be a firewall that blocks your requests